# get data from 2 sources

Tags: asynchronous, angular, rxjs

I'm learning programming and async using promise or observable and it's a bit hard to understand
I have 2 data sources, posts (with user id who posted it), and users, what I want to achieve is simply to display post  with some users info like image, name, etc, how to I proceed?

This is how I get my sources:

```
  allUsers() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.rootRef.child('users').once('value', snapshot => {
        const data = snapshot.val()
        const users = Object.keys(data).map(id => new User(id, data[id]))
        resolve(users)
      })
    })
  }
```

for posts

```
  allPosts(): Subject<Post[]> {
const postsObservable = new BehaviorSubject<Post[]>(null)

this.rootRef.child('posts').on('value', snapshot => {
  const data = snapshot.val()
  const posts = Object.keys(data)
    .map(id => new Post(id, data[id]))
    .sort((lhs, rhs) => rhs.date.getTime() - lhs.date.getTime())

  postsObservable.next(posts)
})

return postsObservable
```

}

Do I need to add user data like image and name when a user posts something, or is it possible to do it this way.

Comment: You can use smth like `combineLatest` `zip` or `withLatestFrom` for combining your data.

Answer (score 1):

I would call your getUsers method when posts are received. This way you would have both data. You would call the next method after having set the user hints into posts:

```
allPosts(): Subject<Post[]> {
  const postsObservable = new BehaviorSubject<Post[]>(null)

  this.rootRef.child('posts').on('value', snapshot => {
    const data = snapshot.val()
    const posts = Object.keys(data)
      .map(id => new Post(id, data[id]))
      .sort((lhs, rhs) => rhs.date.getTime() - lhs.date.getTime())

    this.getUsers().then(users) => {
      posts.forEach((post) => {
        // Set user hints into posts
      });
      postsObservable.next(posts);
    });
  });

  return postsObservable;
}
```

Comment: didnt get it working with your solution otherwise, found an another solution using userRef orderbykey equal to data.val().user in my post function , seems to works fine